# Sort order changed when we add () paranthesis to a column value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table where the data in the table looks like the below.

[image]

The sorting of the data should be based on Code,Model,SequenceNo,Qual1 (Order by Code,Model,SequenceNo,Qual1)
I have prepared the SQL query below which gives perfect result.

```
SELECT Market
    ,Year
    ,Make
    ,BatchNo
    ,BatchLineNo
    ,SequenceNo
    ,Code
    ,Model
    ,Qual1
    ,Qual2
    ,TRANSACTION
FROM TABLE1
ORDER BY Code
    ,Model
    ,SequenceNo
    ,Qual1
```

I have to include paranthesis () to Code column when ever the value of transaction column is either DD or DC
I prepared the SQL query below which runs fine and got the output like this but sort order changed eventhough the order by clause is same in two result sets.

```
SELECT Market
    ,Year
    ,Make
    ,BatchNo
    ,BatchLineNo
    ,SequenceNo
    ,
    ,CASE 
        WHEN (
                TRANSACTION = 'DC'
                OR TRANSACTION = 'DD'
                )
            THEN '(' + Code + ')'
        ELSE Code
        END AS Code Model
    ,Qual1
    ,Qual2
    ,TRANSACTION
FROM TABLE1
ORDER BY Code
    ,Model
    ,SequenceNo
    ,Qual1
```

[image]
I am not sure how to achieve the Code with parenthesis as well as sort order similar to my first result set.

Comment: Can you post sample data as text instead of an image? [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a computed column with your logic and use it to order?

Eventually (if you always order by those 4 columns) you could event CONCAT the 4 columns and only use one column for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [ASCII table] the `"("` is the number `"40"`, the `"*"` is the number `"42"` and the `"2"` is the number `"50". The order is for this reason. You need to create the table and then, call again the table and change the values, for example:

```
Select Market
  ,Year
  ,Make
  ,BatchNo
  ,BatchLineNo
  ,SequenceNo
  ,
  ,CASE 
    WHEN (
      TRANSACTION = 'DC'
        OR TRANSACTION = 'DD'
    )
      THEN '(' + Code + ')'
    ELSE Code
  ,Code Model
  ,Qual1
  ,Qual2
  ,TRANSACTION
FROM (
  SELECT Market
    ,Year
    ,Make
    ,BatchNo
    ,BatchLineNo
    ,SequenceNo
    ,Code
    ,END AS Code Model
    ,Qual1
    ,Qual2
    ,TRANSACTION
  FROM TABLE1
  ORDER BY Code
    ,Model
    ,SequenceNo
    ,Qual1
) table
```

Comment: We can't use order by clause inside subquery

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the ORDER BY gives priority to order to the columns from the column list and not from the tables. You could force to order by the table's column by using a qualified name.

```
SELECT Market
    ,Year
    ,Make
    ,BatchNo
    ,BatchLineNo
    ,SequenceNo
    ,
    ,CASE 
        WHEN (
                TRANSACTION = 'DC'
                OR TRANSACTION = 'DD'
                )
            THEN '(' + Code + ')'
        ELSE Code
        END AS Code Model
    ,Qual1
    ,Qual2
    ,TRANSACTION
FROM TABLE1 AS T
ORDER BY T.Code
    ,Model
    ,SequenceNo
    ,Qual1;
```

If for some reason, you're going to reorder the values in your displaying application, you need to remove the parenthesis again or add a different column to order by it.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd remove the parens by creating a column (maybe via a view?) and keeps only the contents inside the parens, thus:z
(3)()(6)() would become '3 6 '
(3)(H)(6)(2) would become 3H62

and so on. Sort on that new column.

Simplest solution by my reckoning.